# Joomla and nginx page hang while refreshing

Tags: mysql, joomla, nginx

I’ve been installing Joomla on nginx powered server. Everything worked as per initial plan and I’ve installed the Joomla on the server. Even set-up the custom theme.

The problem occurs when I refresh a page in the site (both admin / front end). You can preview the site [here](http://nickies.proitzen.com/).

Also I could see that some js/css files are not properly delivered when refresh hit. It says “pending” in chrome developer tab.

Below is the nginx config for the site

```
server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /var/apps/nickies/public_html;
    # index index.html index.htm;
    index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name nickies.proitzen.com;
    #fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
       # fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        #fastcgi_read_timeout 180;

#   gzip on;
#gzip_http_version 1.1;
#gzip_comp_level 6;
#gzip_min_length 1100;
#gzip_buffers 4 8k;
#gzip_types text/plain application/xhtml+xml text/css application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascr$
#  gzip_proxied     any;
# gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

    # deny running scripts inside writable directories
        location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
                return 403;
                error_page 403 /403_error.html;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         #   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        }

    # caching of files 
        location ~* \.(ico|pdf|flv)$ {
                expires 1y;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|xml|txt)$ {
                expires 14d;
        }
}
```

Could this be a problem with nginx or Joomla installation? Can someone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`application/x-javascr$` should be `application/x-javascript;`.

Side note: The documentation at http://docs.joomla.org/Nginx seems to contain this error. It resembles the screen output in an editor when word wrap is disabled and the end of the line is truncated, so this may be a copy-and-paste error on behalf of the document editor.